# How WebGrease is dependent on Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization package ?

Tags: webgrease

Could not load file or assembly 'WebGrease' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: I found solution but still didn't get it according to question title.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180158/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-webgrease-or-one-of-its-dependencies

Comment: Do Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization package come with any VS install OR Mvc updates ?